# Mapping with Shapely Polygons

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

I am at a loss to get the following code to work. For whatever reason, the GeoPandas *.plot() doesn't work, but I want to use both Pandas and GeoPandas for some simple plots.

I have been trying to take the Shapely objects from GeoPandas and plot them on a Basemap. The problem is that the polygons won't plot. I iterate through them from the GeoPandas.geometry, add them to the axes collection, and then use plot() - to no avail. Basemap seems to work fine, the code doesn't give any errors, but the polygons - counties - don't appear...

Thank you for the help!

```
import geopandas as gpd
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import matplotlib as mpl
import mpl_toolkits.basemap as base
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counties_file = r'C:\Users\...\UScounties\UScounties.shp'
counties = gpd.read_file(counties_file)

#new plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=300)
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax = ax = plt.gca()

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = counties.total_bounds

#map
m = base.Basemap(llcrnrlon=minx, llcrnrlat=miny,
             urcrnrlon=maxx, urcrnrlat=maxy,
             resolution='h', area_thresh=100000,
             projection='merc')

patches = []

#add polygons
for poly in counties.geometry:
    #deal with single polygons and multipolygons
    if poly.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        p = PolygonPatch(poly, facecolor='blue', alpha=1)
        #plt.gca().add_patch(p)
        #ax.add_patch(p)
        patches.append(p)

    elif poly.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
        for single in poly:
            q = PolygonPatch(single,facecolor='red', alpha=1)
            #ax.add_patch(p)
            patches.append(q)

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.1)
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawcountries(linewidth=.25,linestyle='solid')
m.drawstates(linewidth=.25,linestyle='dotted')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')

ax.add_collection(mpl.collections.PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True))
ax.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: What's wrong? Elaborate on your issue.

Comment: What didn't work with the GeoPandas `plot()` method?  It doesn't handle map projections yet, but it should show a plot in the data's coordinate system.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your shapefile is in the right projection system. Basemap is currently set to Mercator Projection. After that it worked for me.